# How to display multiple array indexes on the same line

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have 2 global arrays one holding names, another holding numbers. I want to display the corresponding index from each array on the same line.

Example:

```
Array 1: name1, name2, name3
Array 2: 776,   66565, 5565
```

Desired output:

```
name1 776
name2 66565
name3 5565
```

What I have so far (the `$global:names` array is pulled from another script):

```
$UserResponse = "Y"
$global:Num = @()

while ("$UserResponse" -ne "N") {
  foreach ($Name in $Global:Names) {
    $global:Num += Read-Host "Please enter number for $Name"
    $UserResponse = Read-Host  "Would you like to another number[Y/N]? "
  }
}

if ($UserResponse -eq "N") {
  $Global:Names   $Global:Num
}
```

Comment: @briantist code is updated

Comment: I think you are looking for a hash table instead of two arrays. Run `help about_Hash_Tables` for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Bill_Stewart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2102693/bill-stewart) pointed out in the comments to your question: use a [hashtable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847780.aspx) if you want the output as a list of key/value pairs.

```
$ht = @{}

foreach ($Name in $Global:Names) {
  $num = Read-Host "Please enter number for $Name"
  $ht[$Name] = $num
}

$ht
```